# Jquery Drag and drop to specific text

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a text string in my grid in follwoing format

Pawan/tiwari/idof22/vf

i want to implement drag and drop of this string in textbox.

but how can i determine which substring was clicked

suppose if user click on tiwari and drop it in text box then only tiwari will be in textbox.

Thanks

Comment: can you modify the string?  can you wrap each section in its own <span> tag?

Comment: Yes i did it,but can u tell me i can do it by jquery

Comment: ek tiwari sab pe bhari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got answere of my question.
I have created span tag dynamically but this span tag is not draggable so when i am genrating this span tag i also call $('cssclass').draggable() function now it's working.